# syncronize event with angular ( like thread 'join()' function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I look for something simple as `join()` for thread but for angular.

In my Controller :

```
vehiclesService.getVehicles().then(function(sth){
    $scope.vehicles = sth.data;
    $scope.isend();//this call suck in my mind
});
vehiclesService.getFitment().then(function(sth){
    $scope.fitment = sth.data;
    $scope.isend();//this call suck in my mind
});
vehiclesService.getTagsList().then(function(sth){
    $scope.tags = sth.data;
    $scope.isend();//this call suck in my mind
});
```

I would like something to call a function when all the 3 variables are initialize. the current work. But it's sad in my mind. I also try

```
$scope.$watch('vehicles', function() {
   $scope.isend();
});

$scope.$watch('fitment', function() {
   $scope.isend();
});

$scope.$watch('tags', function() {
   $scope.isend();
});

$scope.isend = function(){
    if($scope.vehicles !== undefined && $scope.fitment !== undefined && $scope.tags !== undefined)
        alert('doSomething');
}
```

it work to, But I found it even worst !

What is the good Way to do so in angular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) - when all of the promises are resolved, the returned promise is resolved.

```
$q.all([
    vehiclesService.getVehicles(),
    vehiclesService.getFitment(),
    vehiclesService.getTagsList()
]).then(function(results) {
   // results is an array
   $scope.isend();
});
```

Comment: ty for Edit , was doing it currently :). Will accept asap!